# Dynamically change the values in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I'm gonna make vehicle speedometer by QT. I have to get data from my arduino speed sensor, and it's is dynamic data. So I have to test my QML file to check if i can display the dynamic data.

KPH and RPM must represent current second, but it doesn't change.

How can I change it?

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
//! [0]
Item {


    id: valueSource
    property real kph: 0
    property real rpm: 1
    property real fuel: 0.5 
    property date curentTime: new Date()
    //property second curentTime: getSeconds()
    property string gear: {
        var g;
        if (kph == 0) {
            return "P";
        }
        if (kph < 30) {
            return "1";
        }
        if (kph < 50) {
            return "2";
        }
        if (kph < 80) {
            return "3";
        }
        if (kph < 120) {
            return "4";
        }
        if (kph < 160) {
            return "5";
        }
    }
    property int turnSignal: gear == "P" && !start ? randomDirection() : -1
    property real temperature: 0.6
    property bool start: true
//! [0]

    function randomDirection() {
        return Math.random() > 0.5 ? Qt.LeftArrow : Qt.RightArrow;
    }

    SequentialAnimation {
        running: true
        loops: 1

        // We want a small pause at the beginning, but we only want it to happen once.
        PauseAnimation {
            duration: 1000
        }


        PropertyAction {
            target: valueSource
            property: "start"
            value: false
        }

        SequentialAnimation {
            loops: Animation.Infinite

            ParallelAnimation{
                NumberAnimation {
                    target: valueSource
                    property : "kph"
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutSine
                    from: 0
                    to: seconds;
                    duration: 1000
                }

                NumberAnimation {
                    target: valueSource
                    property : "rpm"
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutSine
                    from: seconds;
                    to: 0
                    duration: 1000
                }
             }
             ParallelAnimation{
                NumberAnimation {
                    target: valueSource
                    property : "kph"
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutSine
                    from: seconds
                    to: 0;
                    duration: 1000
                }

                NumberAnimation {
                    target: valueSource
                    property : "rpm"
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutSine
                    from: 0;
                    to: seconds
                    duration: 1000
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

It's an example code in QT, and I changed it a little.
I just want to make RPM and KPH instrument panel represents current second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no clock object that you can bind to that will provide the current seconds. You just need to query the current time every second. For that, you will want to use a `Timer` object.

```
property int currentSeconds: (new Date()).getSeconds()

Timer {
    running: true
    repeat: true
    interval: 1000
    onTriggered: {
        var now = new Date();
        currentSeconds = now.getSeconds()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer me. But It's still doesn't change. [link](https://forum.qt.io/topic/83812/change-to-value-of-numberanimation-dynamically-with-another-numberanimation/2)   According to this site, I have to change the code ```loops: Animation.Infinite``` to  ```onStopped: start().``` and I can see that speed is changing. But it was repeated once and it was over. I want the syntax to be repeated over and over again. So.. can you help me again?

Comment: It's not true that it only runs once. You can display the kph value like this: `Text { text: valueSource.kph }` and you will see that its value is constantly changing.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any visual element in your example, so, I added a `ColumnLayout` with some `Text` components to display `kph`, `rpm` and `gear`. Also, there was a compilation error due to there being no `seconds` property, so, I declared one.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
//! [0]
Page {
    id: valueSource
    anchors.fill: parent
    property real kph: 0
    property real rpm: 1
    property real fuel: 0.5
    property date curentTime: new Date()
    //property second curentTime: getSeconds()
    property real seconds: 50
    property string gear: {
        var g;
        if (kph == 0) {
            return "P";
        }
        if (kph < 30) {
            return "1";
        }
        if (kph < 50) {
            return "2";
        }
        if (kph < 80) {
            return "3";
        }
        if (kph < 120) {
            return "4";
        }
        if (kph < 160) {
            return "5";
        }
    }
    property int turnSignal: gear == "P" && !start ? randomDirection() : -1
    property real temperature: 0.6
    property bool start: true
    //! [0]

    function randomDirection() {
        return Math.random() > 0.5 ? Qt.LeftArrow : Qt.RightArrow;
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        Frame {
            Text {
                text: qsTr("%1 kph").arg(kph)
            }
        }
        Frame {
            Text {
                text: qsTr("%1 rpm").arg(rpm)
            }
        }
        Frame {
            Text {
                text: qsTr("Gear: %1").arg(gear)
            }
        }
        Frame {
            Text {
                text: qsTr("Seconds: %1").arg(seconds)
            }
        }
    }

    SequentialAnimation {
        running: true
        loops: 1

        // We want a small pause at the beginning, but we only want it to happen once.
        PauseAnimation {
            duration: 1000
        }


        PropertyAction {
            target: valueSource
            property: "start"
            value: false
        }

        SequentialAnimation {
            loops: Animation.Infinite

            ParallelAnimation {
                NumberAnimation {
                    target: valueSource
                    property : "kph"
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutSine
                    from: 0
                    to: seconds;
                    duration: 1000
                }

                NumberAnimation {
                    target: valueSource
                    property : "rpm"
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutSine
                    from: seconds;
                    to: 0
                    duration: 1000
                }
            }
            ParallelAnimation {
                NumberAnimation {
                    target: valueSource
                    property : "kph"
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutSine
                    from: seconds
                    to: 0;
                    duration: 1000
                }

                NumberAnimation {
                    target: valueSource
                    property : "rpm"
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutSine
                    from: 0;
                    to: seconds
                    duration: 1000
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://qmlonline.kde.org/?code=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-ZFgM5GGEgm5CkyWYL+XAAGTtuBmTGFeAAflqSVYIAuwCK6BgwDE9zgQQAtMM0dD1rDtuAqls9oCFhmoZ0XnAAEYQaRwmB9oISCKPcxWOwkNozZJTsRDlgQUfj96vxiz6NEnmfIALJbCkeBQMOn6zgAfPMixwIOSB4GoriZDAACCUCSBwQTIQASjWKSYdh7Air4EptKI4QgIwmg6Ho3qigAYpBAJMTGByuAAHvAAExj42y8UEACOMgHFANz8gApAQDRNPydx4IUzjGikDwCfqeopssrEaOx-GilxvEcZpcBCTAoniZJMlyf0ICKcpUCqfZGkCTpFF6npBk5j4xl8b5RIWVZElSQA4niQSyY5Kk3I2UBuTGHnil5bHuIZnL+aZmnBXAYmhfyoIIswSJwNFSmxfC4KJT6yVacslHLKCIkROIwBhBhjCgFs058hltQoIwXWMM4V5QDe6pSKeYClcMeqmHAdDuGwSTwBocIgGEUwFCgbxwFs5kpO4R6uM4TDDc4AA0x6MWw7hiFINQreIfiVhAcApBoYCVHyYhxHgepOLtridd1v7ZaKzB7D1YhDNY8PaY+gMrloGGTr1EOcheznWkEoThFEMRxIFZZaEE-K9rA-KBfjERBJkYRvIjerNa1U4dV1m3g-1yxTZ0pWg1zvV4AAkow2Rddsj6aU4kG5K4UiCzDfWBcsAByKAgCdUBK9zquitjwJ42EETRHsxNmaKpNzgK9LU5bnK9DI2J4OMlRBAAohozsjaLjAAPJ6NWZz65ymSSIM8yh0FEBBFViLkQ7vhQ5Bv5wwjSeNQ7Gta1UusYzzAmG7jIQm4T5vxEny4Ht05P2fbVc+E7Ltu4CXs+84fuByCTCV430wR3HYIJ9HywwLHUf9xs0Np3ABDw6iDt1Q1gWy1tCv52+hecjn2ubyrU-F5ZpcE2bsR9431vk3bo++M3vut573su2L3fBxfVfh5+Q-FTIt+CRPawicq4p2VunRelss6W13nnTmytMZmSPsbU+RMP5JyvgKeu-84D307o-OA7cX4ByDr3bBX9I5AOwePH+4JsGgNnvPDOS9Ap1RLCQMUQA)

Comment: Thank you bro! It is such a perfect code and site. But, also when I compiled it at the site, the seconds doesnt' change. So can you change that seconds with real time?

Comment: @joe you can make it do anything you want. Even though I made your program compile, I didn't really understand the intent of your program and the purpose of kph, rpm, gear, and seconds.

Comment: actually, I want to get data from other sensors. and to do that first, I have to make this QML file that can operate with dynamic data. So my intent is to make the rpm follow the current time seconds. I add ```property real seconds: curentTime.getSeconds();``` but it still doesn't work dynamically. the second just fixed.

Comment: could you check this again?? the seconds cahnged, but KPH, RPM is just fixed. [link](tinyurl.com/2j7fmsmt)

Comment: @joe I see that you incorporate the Timer logic that JarMan proposed. That's cool. Seems that you can manipulate/simulate everything. I'm confused as to why kph, rpm get their values based on the current value of seconds. But, hey, I presume you have a reason for that. The intent of the algorithm is not clear to me.